# Line break after first word

Tags: html, css

How can I break a line in css or html for a button link after the first word. So example:

Our Story <- Without line Break

Our
Story     <- With line break

This inside a link that is tied to a class in my css file that gives it its pretty button look. There are 5 buttons in a row and all need to have this. I have tried using padding and a `<br/>` but just dont work at all.

```
<a href="story.php" class="button_nav"/>Our Story</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/br) to add a line break ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/RXdw4/)):

```
<a href="story.php" class="button_nav">Our<br>Story</a>
```

An alternate and suggested solution would be to wrap the first word in a `<span>` and style it with CSS ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/RXdw4/2/)):

```
<a href="story.php" class="button_nav"><span>Our</span> Story</a>
```

```css
a.button_nav {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
span {
    display:block;
}
```